# Ember.js change route without page reload

Tags: ember.js, routes, reload

I am planning an Ember web app which I want to operate on one page without page reloads.

However, I also want to be able to share the state of the app at any time, and therefore make use of Ember's URL-centric design.

As a total Ember noob, I am wondering if and how Ember accomplishes this (relying on routes, but without page reloads).

Any info is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ember has two mechanisms, `history.pushState` and bookmarks (#) (`website.com/home#foo`).  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/  Both of them allow you to change the url, without refreshing the page.

Comment: Now that I know this it seems that Ember does this by default!  Is this true?

Comment: Yup, it's built in and works on it's own

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on "Query Parameters" (see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/)) as that is the feature it sounds like you are looking for.